# In Sails express node js how to display an ad while the requested page loads

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, ads, latency

Some data processing takes a few seconds once the server has received the client's request...

**How can we display an advertisement while the client waits for the payload** ?

Same question with and without AJAX

*We may not use a library or framework on top of Sails, unless necessary*

Comment: This may be easier to implement client-side.  Are you using a framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a simple loading graphic, and just replace it with whatever image you want:

HTML

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

CSS

```
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('images/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

A simple jQuery function:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
```

[Demo](http://dev.bradsknutson.com/demos/page-loader/)

Source: [Display Loading Image While Page Loads](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/)

If you need to do it without jQuery, it is slightly more involved, but you can get more information in this thread:

[$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)